# "Не бойся собаки" or "не бойся собаку"?

Tags: падежи

Я уехал из России в возрасте 10-и лет. Моя жена не русскоязычная, но с детьми я говорю по-русски. Глагол "бояться" требует родительного падежа, т.е., кого? чего? а не кого? что?. Если память мне не изменяет, я детям всё время говорил "не бойся собаку" (т.е., в винительном падеже вместо родительного). С точки зрения грамматики, это, конечно, неправильно. Но мне кажется, что в современной русской речи, неправильная форма встречается чаще правильной. Это так?

Comment: Исследование на эту тему можно найти [здесь](http://diplomba.ru/work/76639).

Comment: Не может не вызывать уважение попытка вырастить детей билингвами.

Comment: Дело не в конкретном глаголе, а в частице "не". "Бойся собаку", но "не бойся собаки". "Я пишу стихи", но "я не пишу стихов".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я позволю себе не согласиться с @Schullz. Предложение "Я боюсь собаки" для меня звучит совершенно нормально и приемлемо. Так же, как *боюсь огня*, *боюсь высоты*, *боюсь измены*.

Having said that, -- чем дольше носитель языка провёл вдали от языковой среды, тем заметнее такому носителю признаки явления под названием "распад падежной системы". Ваш пример -- один из признаков этого процесса. Я не возьмусь разбирать в деталях частные случаи вытеснения родительного падежа винительным, но вытеснение это очевидно любому сколько-нибудь внимательному наблюдателю. Всё чаще встречаются такие, например, формы как *прошу прощени**е***.

Comment: Прошу прощение говорят часто люди вполне себе никогда не покидавшие русскую языковую среду, возможно мы просто являемся свидетелями редкуции падежной системы - просто эволюция языка.

Comment: Да, я и имел в виду людей, никогда не покидавших языковой среды. Покинувшие увезли с собой старые нормы, и распад падежной системы им очевиднее.

Answer (score 4):

> Не бойся собаки = Don't fear a dog.
>
> Не бойся собаку = Don't fear the dog.

Comment: Где-то я с Вами согласен, но по-моему, для первого случая, было-бы естественней сказать "не бойся собак".

Comment: @Aryeh да, но я могу предположить случай, когда предполагается, что дом сторожит одна собака, а не несколько

Comment: @Aryeh вот как раз от *собак* (т.е. стаи) лучше держаться подальше...

Comment: где-то на этот счет было правило.  второй вариант не всегда применим. это что-то вроде того как меняется смысл фразы в английском от того, поставили ли мы герундий или инфинитив в качестве дополнения к глаголу -иногда меняется, иногда нет, а иногда неправильно.

Answer (score 3):

Литературной нормой является использование родительного падежа (потому что винительный падеж "занят" постфиксом -ся), однако для одушевленных предметов винительный падеж тоже допускается.

Когда вы говорите "не бойся собаку" - вы подразумеваете, что собака имеет некоторую близость к вам. Это может быть "родственная" близость - в том случае если это ваша собака; либо же это может быть близость "географическая" - если собака рядом с вами, вы на нее показываете и говорите что эту конкретную собаку не надо бояться.

Использование винительного падежа для неодушевленного предмета обычно означает олицетворение (литературный прием). Также винительный падеж может использоваться для процедуры ("я боюсь маникюр") - лично для меня звучит дико, но автор исследования таких примеров, по-видимому, накопал достаточно.

---

PS Спасибо [Andrey Chernyakhovskiy](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/2284/andrey-chernyakhovskiy) за [ссылку на исследование](http://diplomba.ru/work/76639)  в комментарии.

Answer (score -1):

Если отвечать на вопрос из заголовка, то да, кто-нибудь (и много кто) говорит.
"бойся собаки" и "бойся собаку" оба выглядят приемлемо

Но в предложении "я боюсь собаку" только один вариант приемлем.